# How to create a button to filter posts (list) by meta value

Tags: posts, categories

I have a category.php page that lists posts from each category.
Above that list, I have three buttons. One that filters by title (asc), other by "most recent" and  the third by "most viewed".
I can get the first two to work well, but the third does not.
Can anybody help?

Code:

```
<div id="bot-form">
                       <input type="button" value="Alphabetical order" class="bot-filtro" onclick="window.location.href='?orderby=title&order=asc'" />

                       <input type="button" value="Most recent" class="bot-filtro" onclick="window.location.href='?orderby=date'" />

                       <input type="button" value="Most popular" class="bot-filtro" onclick="window.location.href='?sortby=views'" />
                  </div><!-- fim #bot-form -->
```

Comment: do you have any hits counter for the posts ?

Comment: WP doesn't track post views, you'll need to source that data separately and figure out how you're going to save the data ( hint: don't store it in post meta, it'll have major performance issues and suffer from race conditions, so it'll massively undercount if it doesn't just break, pull the data from a 3rd party instead ). Also doing it via JS won't be the same as doing it without JS, I'd suggest you do it entirely in PHP first

Comment: I could filter posts list by "most viewed", but without a buttom.

Comment: This is the code I use in the home page:


     $args = array(
 'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 5, // posts por coluna
    'cat' => 5, // Use o id da categoria "Nomes Masculinos"
 'meta_key' => 'my_post_viewed',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'=> 'DESC'
);
$q = new WP_Query( $args);